# drupal facet api + search api: empty page (no result) default

Tags: search, drupal-7

I'm trying to create a faceted search page in Drupal 7 and it's almost done.

These are the modules I used for faceted search.
*Facet API *Search API *Database search *Search Facets *Search Views *Entity API

I created a page with views for faceted search. There are blocks for filtering etc. Here, **the problem is the search page shows all results (entries) default**, without filtering. If I apply some filter criteria it correctly shows the results, no problem here.

What I want is to show nothing default, an empty result area in the search page I created.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Show facet filter even if there is no result](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/38986/show-facet-filter-even-if-there-is-no-result). There's a patch available that let's you [show facets on "no results found" search](https://www.drupal.org/node/2219897).

From what I understand that may be what you're looking for…

Answer (score 0):

I have done the similar thing using [this article](http://highrockmedia.com/blog/using-drupal-views-arguments-show-results-only-when-filter-used).

Only difference is that i have exposed filters rather then facet filters. But this will give you idea how to do so.

Hope this will help.